# Does the hook function used in SetWindowsHookExA need to be in dll?

Tags: c++, msdn, setwindowshookex

I am trying to read system keyboard events in my c++ application using [SetWindowsHookExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Application is able to get the system keyboard events as long as the hooking is done in a dll. If I try to create hook inside my application code (without a dll), I am not getting keyboard events.  Is it mandatory for hook functions to be in a dll? If yes, is there a reason?

Comment: I'm not sure the reason, but that's always been the case. Back in Win3.1 days there were good reasons, but I'm not sure there is anymore.

Comment: The documentation you've linked explains the reason in detail in the remarks section

Comment: WH_KEYBOARD: yes.  WH_KEYBOARD_LL: no, message pump required.  The reason is that the former runs the callback inside the process that acquired the keystroke.  With the big advantage that the keyboard state is reliable, matters to accurately detect the state of the modifier keys.  And the big disadvantage that writing a DLL that can reliably run in any process is quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

No, a hook does not need to be in a DLL. See the description of the parameters:

> [in] lpfn
>
> Type: HOOKPROC
>
> A pointer to the hook procedure. If the dwThreadId parameter is zero
> or specifies the identifier of a thread created by a different
> process, the lpfn parameter must point to a hook procedure in a DLL.
> **Otherwise**, lpfn can point to a hook procedure in the code associated
> with the current process.

You can have it in your EXE, but then you'll have to use a thread from your process. And IIRC this thread will need to pump messages.